# Re-render a React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a profile component with URL: '/profile/id'.

Now, suppose I have two users having IDs: id_A and id_B.

I am at URL: '/profile/id_A' and I have a button which sends me to URL: '/profile/id_B'  using:

```
<Link to={{ pathname: `/profile/id_B` }}></Link>
```

Now, my component won't re-render because there is no state change for which I cannot retrieve my user-data from the server since all my requests are done on componentDidMount.

So, how do I re-render my component for the above scenario?

UPD 1:
This is my Route code:

```
<Route path="/profile/:userId" component={Profile} />
```

UPD 2:
I have 3 components nested:
Profile -> FollowList -> Card
I have my link in my card component and this is the code for routing it to 'profile/id_B'.

```
<Link to={{ pathname: `/profile/${this.props.user.userId}` }}></Link>
```

Can this be a problem that the below answers are not working?

Comment: It appears you're using a routing library. You should say which one in your question. The answer probably lies in the lib's documentation.

Comment: @HugoMota I'm using the React-router-dom.

Comment: can you show your router code where you have declared your routes? Are you using render or component in Routes

Comment: @ShauryaVardhanSingh I'm using component in my routes. I have added the route code above.

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, to re-render a component you can use `shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps)` function. Basically React triggers this function to ask you if component should be updated (re-rendered) and here you can write the logic you need to re-render the component. Take a look at [this](https://blog.bitsrc.io/react-16-lifecycle-methods-how-and-when-to-use-them-f4ad31fb2282) guide.

Comment: I used your method but the maximum update depth exceeded. It looks like setState can't be used inside shouldComponentUpdate().

Comment: No, shouldComponentUpdate() must not be used like componentDidMount(). shouldComponentUpdate() returns a boolean that if is equal to true then the component will be re-rendered again. So in your shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) you have to write something like: if(condition_to_re-render) return true;

Answer (score 0):

It appears you need to use the `Route` component, placing your "pages" on them with one of the designed methods. You can read more about it here:

https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route

The recommended way of doing it is using the children of the Route, which is supposed to mount the page when the url matches, and unmount when they don't. So something like:

```
<Route path="/to">
    <My Page/>
</Route>
```

Comment: This is what I have been using.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that your component is getting rerendered but as you have your code in componentDidMount and it is called only once when the component is mounted so you are facing the difficulty.

So to fix this problem you need to unmount and mount your component again, this can be done using the inline function inside component prop.

According to [react-router-docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/component)

> When you use component (instead of render or children, below) the router uses React.createElement to create a new React element from the given component. That means if you provide an inline function to the component prop, you would create a new component every render. This results in the existing component unmounting and the new component mounting instead of just updating the existing component.

So you need to refactor your code and use

```js
<Route path="/profile/:userId" component={() => (<Profile />)} />
```

This will mount and unmount on component on each render and you can access the component did mount.

#### Alternate Solution

You can also use ComponentDidUpdate and check on each update if the id is same or not, if id is not same fetch the data.

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (prevProps.match.params.userId !== this.props.match.params.userId) {
    //call your fetch function here and then set the data in state
    setState({
      userId: data,
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but none of them seem to work. I don't get why the first one isn't working but when I tried the alternate solution the "history.location.pathname" of both the prevProps and this.props are the same and its's actually the new path that I want it to go i.e, 'profile/id_B'.

Comment: @MukeshGupta created the codeSandbox for the alternate solution https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-snyder-csjw8?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Even I was doing something like that but both my prevProps and this.props have the same value whereas the should be different. Somehow I managed to get what I wanted but now I want to know why does the prevProps and this.props have the same value? Is it because of the nested components?

Comment: @MukeshGupta cant say for sure without looking at the code, if possible can you share your code on codesandbox